# Why doesn't "Hello!" appear at the start of your post?

Tags: support

I am new here.

See this screenshot:

> [image: Before posting]

I wrote a greeting in my post above, but after posting it became:

> [image: After posting]

"Hello," was omitted. I tried to edit it in several times ;) I have one question and one answer to date. In both of them, I experienced same behavior with "Hello!". I am not complaining though; I am just hoping that someone might explain what is it about.

Comment: It is an invoking keyword for a session or a conversation, while this site is for answering and asking questions which are technical not social!

Comment: Hello is noise. We are not a forum, Hello, and thanks and that kind of stuff is irrelevant for the question. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: It’s an automated filter.

Comment: Welcoming someone to stackoverflow is also irrelevant of course, but filters are just dumb filters. Which is why I don't like them, this is a pretty confusing experience.

Comment: @gnat now I see its definitely a duplicate, however, _strange, hidden word_ reads a bit obscure and is less likely to appear in relevant searches. Please correct me if I am mistaken

Comment: @UmairAhmad You're right, which is why your question won't be deleted but marked as a duplicate, so there's a higher chance people find either the original question or this question, when they have a similar problem.

Comment: @Stijn just your comment made me understand how duplicate_flag works here. _Gracias_ (since thanks may be omitted :)

Comment: Yes, *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)* is very much related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Salutations or greetings are noise in Questions and Answers, and shouldn't be included. The focus is very clearly on the topic itself, and not on usual pleasantries.

Seems like this is some automatic system correction if you really do start your answer with `Hello!`, but even if it wasn't auto removed, an edit removing it would have been justified.

In general, try to avoid adding noise like that to your answers and questions.